# Most efficient way to reverse a stack and add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures, performance, stack, arraylist

I have two collections - an ArrayList and a Stack.  I use the stack because I needed some simple pop/push functionality for this bit of code. The ArrayList is essentially the out variable as this is a small section of code in the function.

So, the variables are defined as such, then code is run to add elements to the stack.

```
ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

/* other code.. */

Stack<String> lineStack = new Stack<String>();

/* code that adds stuff to the stack */
```

The question is, now that I have a fully populated stack, how do I place it in the out ArrayList in a reverse order then from the pop order.

My first thought up solution was

```
 while(!lineStack.empty()) {
     out.add(0, lineStack.pop());
 }
```

... which works, but I worry about the efficiency of adding an element to the beginning of the ArrayList (which forces all existing elements to need to shift.. it's a linked list (I believe).. big deal.. but still a concern). Also, I am running this through a loop... perhaps unnecessarily.

So, my second solution that didn't involve looping (at least in my code, i'm sure the back end calls are doing it).

```
 List l = lineStack.subList(0, lineStack.size());
 out.addAll(l);
```

I know I don't need to allocate the list, but it'll keep for cleaner code. However, I am not sure if this will give me a particularly helpful performance gain.

So, my question is:  Which of these will likely be most efficient for SMALL to MEDIUM size sets? If there is a more efficient solution, what would it be?

Comment: Adding to beginning of `ArrayList` is costly; it is an `ArrayList` not a `LinkedList`.  Adding it to the beginning is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Please note that `Stack` is a subclass of `Vector` (which is almost similar to `ArrayList`).  While discharged, maybe you can just it as `Vector` instead of copying the list.

Comment: That's what I figured. Turns out I am just going with the out.addAll(lineStack)  method.  I don't need to even turn it into a list object. That's unneeded overhead. The iterator of the Stack will play the right direction despite being a stack

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Iterable<T>` implementation order of `Stack<T>` goes in the order you want anyway, so you can just use

```
new ArrayList<String>(stack);
```

Here's a short but complete example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push("Bottom");
        stack.push("Middle");
        stack.push("Top");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(stack);

        for (String x : list)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
Bottom
Middle
Top
```

(which is the opposite order to what you'd get if you popped them).

EDIT: One other question - do you really need it in an `ArrayList<String>` anyway? `Stack<T>` implements `List<T>`; what special features of `ArrayList` do you need? (I'm not saying you *don't* need them, just checking!)

Comment: You made a very good point!

I can't reinitialize the ArrayList (not guaranteed to be empty), but since the Iterator is going to give it to me in the right order, I can just  out.addAll(lineStack);   .. I don't know why I bothered making it into a list. *facepalm*

Thanks!

Comment: To the edit: Aye. The ArrayList is being used elsewhere and is part of the API - Can't really change it :(.

Comment: That's absolutely fair enough. I'll leave the edit in for posterity, just in case anyone else finds themselves in a similar situation but where they *could* just use the stack :)

Answer (score 3):

Stack is subclass of Collections and Collections has [reverse method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)), So you can just do -

```
   Stack originalStack = ...
   Collections.reverse(originalStack);
```

Comment: This works because `Stack` implements `List`, not because `Stack` is a `Collection`; look at the parameter type to `Collections#reverse`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need it as an array, but another stack would work, why not:

`Stack<String> reversedStack = new Stack<String>();
     while (!oldStack.empty())
     {
         reversedStack.push(oldStack.pop());
     }`

Quick, simple, and easy to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the ArrayList and add a pop and push method.
Use this as the Stack class.

When you are ready, assign it to an Arraylist variable and you're ready

Answer (score 0):

making use of Stack.toArray is simple:

```
@Test
public void stackToList() {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push("aaa");
    stack.push("bbb");
    stack.push("ccc");
    List<String> list=  Arrays.asList(stack.toArray(new String[0]));
    Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), list);
}
```