# Working With Stack

Tags: java

it has been to long since i asked here ..

I have this homework which has this Q Remove The Bottom Of The Stack I did it 
good but not great .. 
but now i have a Q is how to reverse the stack i did it by using another stack 
is there a better way 
this is what i did :

```
    public static<T> void removeLast(LinkedList<T> st)
    {
        LinkedList<T> store = new LinkedList<>();
        while (!st.eamty()){
            store.push(st.pop());
        }

        store.pop();
        while(!store.eamty()){
            st.push(store.pop());
        }


    }
```

some src I found 
[Most efficient way to reverse a stack and add to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245060/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-stack-and-add-to-an-arraylist)

https://www.careercup.com/question?id=12689669

Comment: If you got the answer please make the answer as accepted @Salman

Answer (score 0):

I'd made the following instead:

```
 public static<T> void removeLast(LinkedList<T> st)
{
    return st.removeLast();
}
```

But this is not a queue meant to be used and is also quite "expensive" operation ...

Comment: Actually, `removeLast` is a cheap operation on a `LinkedList`

Comment: My fault you're right @StephenC don't really know what i was thinking. Especially with the Doubly-linked list implementation and reference both to the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `LinkedList<T>` is not just a `Stack`.  It is a `List`.  In fact, it is a list class with a specific operation to removing the last element.  (The `removeLast` method is defined by the `Deque` interface which `LinkedList` implements.  The `Deque` abstraction is a "double ended queue"; i.e. something that can act as both a FIFO and a LIFO - a queue and a stack.)

So if you are able to the fact that this *representation* of a stack is implemented as a linked list, then the solution is to call that method.

On the other hand, if you are required / restricted to implementing your `removeLast` using only "stack-like" methods in the `LinkedList` API, then your approach of popping all elements to a temporary stack is probably as good as you can get.